# Create URL for action with attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I have action in controller with ASP.NET MVC 5 attribute routing.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
  [Route("{srcFileFormat}-to-{dstFileFormat}")]
  public ActionResult Converter(string srcFileFormat, string dstFileFormat)
  {
  }
}
```

I am trying to create url and always get **Null** instead of URL. Any suggestion how to use `UrlHelper.Action` and `Attribute Routing` together in my case?

```
@Url.Action("docx-to-pdf", "Home")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Url.Action` we specify the controller name and action method name, not the routing naming or parameters the way you are trying.

We normally do the following way for getting url for a controller action:

```
@Url.Action("Converter", "Home")
```

But as your action method expects two parameters too and you are trying to pass those in, you will need to call it passing the parameters too, like:

```
@Url.Action("Converter", "Home", new {srcFileFormat ="doc",dstFileFormat="pdf"})
```

Now it should generate the url like:

```
localhost:6087/doc-to-pdf
```